# Selenium not working?

Tags: python, selenium, bots

So recently i have been working on a project in python. It is an omegle bot.
But when they disconnect the code just seems to stop. And does not keep running. Why is this?

```
    from selenium import webdriver
import random
import time

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\isak\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
with open('omegle_test_bot.txt', 'r') as words:
    read = words.read()
words = read.split('\n')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get('http://www.omegle.com/')
interests = driver.find_element_by_class_name('newtopicinput')
interests.send_keys('programming\npython\nsoundcloud\nhigh\nweed\n')
time.sleep(7)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="videobtn"]""").click()
time.sleep(2)
def if_disconnect():
     time.sleep(1)
     driver.find_element_by_class_name('disconnectbtn').click()
     Main()
def Main():
    while True:
        text_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name('chatmsg')
        word = random.choice(words)
        text_box.send_keys(random.choice(words))
        driver.find_element_by_class_name('sendbtn').click()

Main()
if_disconenct()
```

Comment: Who disconnect what?! Point on exact line of code that cause your issue

Comment: Is an exception being raised? You may need to put `main()` under a `try` clause and `if_disconnect()` in the except block. Please provide any error messages you are getting!

Comment: @sytech well i had an ide to search for a button on the site that would only appear if the connection broke.

Comment: @sytech so maybe that could work...

Comment: @Andersson when the stranger disconnects the code just stops working

Comment: @Andersson so this is an xpath element that only appears if someone disconnects so i added this to the end of the code:

Comment: try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[7]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/img""").click()
        except Exception as e:
            if e == None:
                Main()
        else:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[7]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/img""").click()
            


Main()

Comment: `      try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[7]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/img""").click()
        except Exception as e:
            if e == None:
                Main()
        else:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[7]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/img""").click()
            


Main()
`

Comment: sorry for the indentation errors it seems you cant paste it like that :P

Comment: @isak, you can use "edit" option to add your code to existed question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your code send messages permanently without any waits: you search input field, send keys, search button, click button over and over again... When your guest disconnects, he trigger page refresh and in some moment your code is unable to find input field or button and script stops. You might need to use `Explicit wait` to wait until your element becomes available before trying to handle it:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

text_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "chatmsg")))
text_box.send_keys(random.choice(words))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "sendbtn"))).click()
```

Also note that this piece of code `word = random.choice(words)` do nothing (you don't use `word` variable in your code).

Because your `main()` has no condition to stop running (contains no `break`), there is no possibility to run `if_disconect()`...ever

Comment: But i dont really understand fully could you implement that code in my code so it would just work like a program? (:

Comment: haha no need Thank u soo much. I just pasted it in in my code and itr worked. Now i need to learn about it and why it works (: Thanks so much (:

Comment: Welcome! Please mark my answer as "Accepted" with check mark if it solved your problem

Comment: btw when you write this: WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "sendbtn"))).click(). What does that 10 mean after driver?

Comment: This means timeout. If expected condition returns `False` within timeout (10 seconds in our case), `TimeOutException` will be raised. You can set as much time (seconds), as you like

Comment: okey thanks (: and btw the 'bot' is working good